# How can I make that the user will be able to search for a multiple texts with textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Today when I type something any text in textBox1 and then click the start button it will search inside files for the text i typed in textBox1.

Now I want to add something somehow that if the user type in the textBox1 for example: hello,hi it will search for hello and also for hi in the files. Not as one string/text but two separated. If I type: hello,hi,world now it will search in same time same files also for hello hi and world.

The textchanged event

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != "" && Directory.Exists(textBox3.Text))
            {
                startButton.Enabled = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default["Setting2"] = textBox1.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                startButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

The start button click event

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label21.Visible = true;
            startButton.Enabled = false;
            stopButton.Enabled = true;
            pauseresumeButton.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                SetWorkerMode(true);
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

Dowork event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            _stopwatch.Restart();
            DirSearch(textBox3.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text, worker, e);
            _stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

The DirSearch method where I search for the text in files.

```
void DirSearch(string rootDirectory, string filesExtension, string textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();
            List<string> restrictedFiles = new List<string>();
            int overallfiles = 0;
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            int numberofdirs = 0;

            try
            {  
                filePathList = SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(rootDirectory, null).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                string ad = err.ToString();
            }
            foreach (string file in filePathList)
            {
                try
                {
                    _busy.WaitOne();
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
                    int var = File.ReadAllText(file).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
                    overallfiles++;
                    if (var == 1)
                    {
                        numberoffiles++;
                        prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = file, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString() });
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
                    }
                    numberofdirs++;
                    label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                        label1.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    restrictedFiles.Add(file);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

In DirSearch the variable textToSearch contains the text I typed in textBox1.
If I typed in textBox1 only HI so like it is now it will search in each file for the existing of HI.

But if I type HI,HELLO,WORLD
Now I want it to search for existing in each file of HI HELLO WORLD not as one text string but each word on it's own existing.

If I type Hi HELLO WORLD then it will search it as one string/text but once the user put , between it should search each word/text.

Comment: just a little comment, you shouldn't call your variables `var`. `var` has a specific meaning in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the input in the textbox based on space, comma's or any other separator and then pass these as individual inputs to your search method, hope this helps